# custom jquery validation and unobtrusive JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to write a custom validation that gives an error if html exists in the textarea when they submit a form.

I have the following - 
its not working and I'm not sure why.

also I don't understand the unobtrusive part 
can someone show me how to do that as I am seeing other examples on SO that have it.

text area has a class"note"
the form is called "noteform"

```
  <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function () {


        $.validator.addMethod('nohtml', function (value, element) {
            var text = $(".note").text();
            if ($(text).length > 0) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }
        }, 'Html not allowed');

    //    // **not sure what to do here**
    //    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('containsnohtml', {}, function (options) {
    //        options.rules['nohtml'] = false;
    //        options.messages['nohtml'] = options.message;
    //    });

        $('#noteform').validate({
            rules: { nohtml: "required nohtml" }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: are you using some kind of validation plugin or something similar?

Comment: im using jquery.validate.min.js

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a couple issues here. One is you're trying to mix unobtrusive and regular jquery validation. If you want to use validate like this then you need to make sure `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` is NOT included. This is because `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` automatically parses and produces a validator for the document and the very first thing that `validate` does is check if there's an existing validator and exits if there is.

If you do decide to go the non-unobtrusive route, be sure not to use the `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add` since it will cause an error without `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`.

I would recommend going with unobtrusive validation though since I think you're using MVC3.
If you're going to go with unobtrusive validation you have two choices, set the data-* attributes yourself by adding `data-val="true" data-val-nohtml="Html not allowed"` to your textarea as suggested by JohnnyO and including a span with `data-valmsg-for="note" data-valmsg-replace="true"` to show the error message. Or you can make your own DataAnnotation attribute.

Here's the code for the addMethod (needed for both kinds of validation)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     (function ($) {
            $.validator.addMethod('nohtml', function (value, element) {
                // Test 'value' for html here. 'value' is the value of the control being validated.
                return true; // Return true or false depending on if it passes or fails validation, respectively.
            }, 'Html not allowed');

        } (jQuery));
    </script>
```

and the javascript needed for the unobtrusive is as follows

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool('nohtml');
```

Regarding how to make a custom validation attribute, since I'm not sure what language you're using, assuming you're using MVC3, or if you even need this info anymore 4 months after you asked, I'm going to simply leave these links for reference.

[A brief comparision of Traditional vs Unobtrusive JavaScript Validation in MVC 3 - Mitchell Trent's Blog](http://mitchelltrent.com/a-brief-comparision-of-traditional-vs-unobtrusive-javascript-validation-in-mvc-3/)
[ASP.NET MVC 3 Custom Validation - Microsoft Developer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg618485)

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't tested this, I think all that you're missing is to wire up the element that you want to validate with the `nohtml` rule. Something like this:

```
$('textarea.note').rules('add', {
  nohtml: true
});
```

Based on some of your description, I assume you're using ASP.NET MVC3.  In that case, you would only need to use the unobtrusive adapter if you're generating the validation attributes server side on your HTML element (e.g. `<textarea data-val="true" data-val-nohtml="Html not allowed"></textarea>`).  In such a case, you'll need the unobtrusive adapter to wire up the element to use your `nohtml` rule.