# dd-mm-yyyy Date Validation Error with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, localization, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, date-format

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC4 application.

**My View Model Class Property**

```
[DisplayName("Birth Date")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must indicate your full birthday")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

**Javascript Code**

```
var dt = new Date();
    $(function () {
        $("#BirthDate").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/images/calendar.gif")",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '1980:dt'
        });
    });
```

**View code**

```
<div class="block">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { @Class = "compel" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate)
                </div>
```

When I run the application in IE and Mozilla Firefox it works fine, but with google chrome, it gives validation error as **The Value 24/12/2012 is invalid for Birth Date**.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Seemingly IE & Firefox use same format as OS while Chrome does not, this sometimes causes an issue with date validation.

Maybe this will solve your problem: [Unobtrusive validation in Chrome won't validate with dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906725/unobtrusive-validation-in-chrome-wont-validate-with-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the problem i have done :

1. add reference to the script datepicker-fr.js (you can find it
   here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n).
2. create a function and add it to my custom javascript file :

   ```
    function extendJQueryDateValidation() {

   // fix date validation for chrome
   jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
       date: function (value, element) {
           var isChrome = window.chrome;
           // make correction for chrome
           if (isChrome) {
               var d = new Date();
               return this.optional(element) ||
               !/Invalid|NaN/.test($.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", value));
           }
               // leave default behavior
           else {
               return this.optional(element) ||
               !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
           }
       }
   });
   }
   ```

   refer to http://devdens.blogspot.com/2011/11/jquery-validation-fix-for-date-format_29.html
3. In the page where i have the date input element i do :

   ```
           $(function () 
        {          
         extendJQueryDateValidation();        
         $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional   ["fr"]);    
                  $("#dateField").datepicker(
       { yearRange: "1980:2015", 
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
    changeMonth: true, 
    changeYear: true });

              });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for date format:
Example: '31/12/1999'

```
 jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
        date: function (value, element) {
            return /^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/.test(value);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for this and found multiple questions here and elsewhere. I found a simple solution and just wanted to share it with future searchers also;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36903550/1997092

> I found the simplest correction of this error to be the following code
>   snippet after calling your validation file;
>
> ```
> jQuery.validator.methods["date"] = function (value, element){
>     var shortDateFormat = "dd/mm/yy";
>     var res = true;
>     try {
>         $.datepicker.parseDate(shortDateFormat, value);
>     } catch (error) {
>         res = false;
>     }
>     return res;
> }
> ```
>
> Even in versions found in 2016 im still having this issue without the
>   above code in Chrome and not Firefox.
>
> This is my preferred solution as it does not require any additional
>   libraries or plugins to work.
>
> I found this code snippet while googling the issue here.

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Please do not post links to [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post. (Further: a link to that question was already provided in a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14361144/1677912).)

Comment: Apologies for trying to share the information. Could you advise what I SHOULD do/have done instead?

Comment: Identify duplicate _questions_ and flag them or vote them to close, depending on your privilege level. Leave a comment on the question, along the lines of "This answer over here may be useful, in _these specific circumstances_". (This is advice from the FAQ link I provided.)