# JQuery DatePicker DateTime Issue in Chrome and Safari Not in IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4

I sent a link to a test site today which I was happy would work. I had developed it primarily on vs so used ie and then firefox/firebug for css.

But, client side validation is being triggered by the jquery datepicker and won't allow people using chrome or safari to go choose a date which doesn't matche a USA date format.

ie 5/5/2013 works just fine. 13/5/2013 don't work.

what am I doing wrong?

the culture is set to

this is my test site... chrome doesn't like the date

http://taxiroutemvc.azurewebsites.net/

thanks

Comment: did you try adding  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding an additional .js file with the following content:

```
jQuery.validator.methods.date = function(value, element) {
var dateRegex = /^(0?[1-9]\/|[12]\d\/|3[01]\/){2}(19|20)\d\d$/;
return this.optional(element) || dateRegex.test(value);};
```

as mentioned in this article...

[Unobtrusive validation in Chrome won't validate with dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906725/unobtrusive-validation-in-chrome-wont-validate-with-dd-mm-yyyy)

hth

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using dateFormat?

```
     $('.datefield').datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
     });
```

In your model for that date field use:

```
   [RegularExpression(@"^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "INVALID DATE. Requires either DD/MM/YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY")]
```

you may have to remove:

```
     [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
```

to work in Chrome.

If not you have to modify jquery.validate.js. This is a known error in WebKit browsers.

Comment: ive got $("#enquiry_pickupTime").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });

Comment: are you using ValidationMessageFor in MVC? Remove that, or use Regex in your models.

Comment: [RegularExpression(@"^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "INVALID DATE. Requires either DD/MM/YYYY or DD-MM-YYYY")]

Comment: ive tried all your suggestions and it sill won't work. certainly looks like a problem with webkit.