# Validate french date format in unobtrusive jQuery Validate in ASP MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'd like to validate the dateformat in ASP MVC 4 with Unobtrusive jQuery Validation.

My Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateTimeNotNullable.cshtml :

```
@model DateTime

@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToShortDateString(), new { maxlength = 10, @class = "editor-datetime", style = "width: 150px" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    if (typeof (jQuery) == 'function')
    {
        $(function () {
            if ($.datepicker) {
                $("#@this.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("")").datepicker();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

But when I put a french date format (dd/MM/yy) ex: 18/04/2013, I always have a valiation error.

I already tryied to use the Microsoft Globalization library, it worked but I had a regression on the validation of the decimal format.
Do you have simple javascript to correct that behaviour ?

Comment: Looks related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906725/unobtrusive-validation-in-chrome-wont-validate-with-dd-mm-yyyy.  If so, there are solutions there.