# Chrome don't accept a specific date format using jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, validation, google-chrome, date

I made a date format with jQuery Validator, in this format: dd/mm/yyyy.

But I'm having a problem with this format in Google Chrome.
In IE or Firefox, the date format is working well, but in Google Chrome, the format accept in maximum 12/12/yyyy. For example, the date 20/12/2014 in IE is ok, but in Chrome, the date is not accept.

The code:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "brDate",
        function(value, element) {
            return value.match(/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/);
        },
        "The correct date format is dd/mm/yyyy."
    );
```

Comment: Welcome to international dates!  Dont validate your dates using a regular expression, instead use date function.  Look up date functions in Jquery and you'll find something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I solved the problem.

```
jQuery.validator.methods["date"] = function (value, element) { return true; }
```

font: [Unobtrusive validation in Chrome won't validate with dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906725/unobtrusive-validation-in-chrome-wont-validate-with-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: For future viewers, note that this would accept any value as a date (decimals, letters, etc). It may be sufficient to do server-side parsing and so you simply want to allow the form to post, but just be aware of the implications.

Comment: This is not really a solution. This just ignore date validation: always `return true`

Answer (score 1):

Most of the validators already have date validation methods.

Which one are you using?

```
http://**formvalidator.net**/#default-validators_dates
<!-- Validate date formatted yyyy-mm-dd -->
<input type="text" data-validation="date">

<!-- Validate date formatted dd/mm/yyyy -->
<input type="text" data-validation="date" data-validation-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
```

I'd suggest to use such validation.

If you want to write pattern you self, you can use this one:

```
^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$
```

MM/dd/yyyy with 100% leap years. Valid since year 1900. MM and DD could have 1 or 2 digits : M/d/yyyy or MM/d/yyyy or M/dd/yyyy

Taken from http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1071

Comment: I tried using data-validation in inputs, but didn't work. For example, I digit 18/15/2014 (dd/mm/yyyy), and this date was registered in DB. It was wrong! But I solved the problem as say below.