# dd-mm-yyyy format for datepicker of MVC is not working in Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker

In my MVC5 Razor code for entering Date of Birth I am using a datepicker as below

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date_of_birth, 
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "m-wrap  datepicker" } })
```

Here for the `model.date_of_birth` an `EditorFor` is calling and making it as a `datepicker` with `@class = datepicker`

Then the datepicker is initiated at the script area with below code

```
 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            autoclose: true
        })
```

Here the date format is `'yyyy-mm-dd'` and it is working fine, but the user want it to be in `dd-mm-yyyy` format. So I changed the format in script as `dd-mm-yyyy`
In Internet Explorer it is working fine but in Chrome it is giving an error for some date

```
eg:  14-05-2015
```

> The field Date of Birth* must be a date.

the date `11-05-2015` is working fine in chrome also. So I guess Chrome is taking the date format in `mm-dd-yyyy`.

The format `'dd-M-yyyy'` is also working correctly only error coming for `dd-mm-yyyy`

Any way to overcome this browser specific error?

**Edit**

```
$.validator.addMethod('date', function (value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }
    var valid = true;
    try {
        $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yyyy', value);
    }
    catch (err) {
        valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
});

$(function () {

 $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            autoclose: true
        })
});
```

Comment: The issue is that jquery.validate.js expects the date in either `MM/dd/yyyy or the ISO format. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969) for solutions.

Comment: @Stephenmuecke one doubt..if it is issue with jquery.validate.js then how it is working in internet explorer.

Comment: No idea - but does anything work correctly with IE :)

Comment: @stephenMuecke i applied the script and changes now even the date less than 12 is also not accepting :( 05/07/2015 is also giving error

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you edit the question to show the actual code you tried (note the `$.validator.addMethod()` should not be inside `document.ready()`)

Comment: Looks OK. Do you have any errors in the browser console? Is the `$.validator.addMethod()` function after `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81146/discussion-between-sachu-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: Dont know whether it will do or not but change  $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yyyy', value);  to $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At last I found a solution.

First I create a new java script file with name `jquery.validate.date.js`
with the below code in it

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
        if ($.browser.webkit) {
            var d = new Date();
            return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(d.toLocaleDateString(value)));
        }
        else {
            return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value));
        }
    };
});
```

It overwrite the date validation function in `jquery.validate.js`

Then i call the script just after `'jquery.validate.js'` like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.val.js")"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.val.date.js")"/>
```

Now the date format dd/mm/yyyy is working in both chrome and IE without any error.

Answer (score 2):

There is a problem with unobtrusive validator for dates in non 'yyyy-MM-dd' format. Similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906725/unobtrusive-validation-in-chrome-wont-validate-with-dd-mm-yyyy).

Solving by disabling validation of dates

```
jQuery.validator.methods["date"] = function (value, element) { return true; }
```

or by using globalization.

In my case i always set input to readonly and add datepicker from jquery.ui. with localization.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.date_of_birth, 
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "m-wrap  datepicker", @readonly="readonly" } })
```

and some js:

```
// include localization for datepicker

$( "#date_of_birth" )
    .datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "ru" ] )
    .datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

Comment: i didn't understand the way u r doing.

Comment: @Sachu just create readonly input and initialize jquery datepicker on it. This allow you to prevent incorrect input from user and always have correct formatted value in field. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set your culture in web.config so that .net expects the date in dd-mm-yyyy format rather than the default mm-dd-yyyy US format.

e.g.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <globalization culture="en-AU" uiCulture="en-AU" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Updated**

Also try annotating the property
e.g.

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]
public DateTime date_of_birth;
```

Comment: Are you annotating the date_of_birth property of the model?... could try adding  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]