# jQuery datepicker dosen't work as excepted

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need my date input to be `dd/MM/yyyy`, but when I use this code:

```
$('#DateTime').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/MM/yyyy' });
```

It shows the date like this: `28/December/20162016`.
Any idea?

Update:
It works now with this format `dd/mm/yy`. But the problem is that, when I pass a date like `17/12/2016` the server says that: (it gets null)

```
The value '17/12/2016' is not valid for DateTime.
```

PS: I'm using ASP.NET MVC and my property is:

```
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime? DateTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: use `mm` instead of `MM` and `yy` instead of `yyyy`. have a look here as well: https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html

Comment: @Jamesonthedog I updated my question.

Comment: I've updated my answer then :)

Comment: Also update `DataFormatString = {0:dd/MM/yyyy}` to  `DataFormatString = {0:dd/mm/yyyy}`

Comment: You can try changing the server machine date time  to desired format. Else you can opt to changing your DB column into string

Comment: You attributes are only applicable when using the `@Html.EditorFor()` and `@Hml.DisplayFor()` methods and do not apply when using a jquery datepicker. If the error is client side, its because you have not reconfigured the `$.validator` (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285458/jquery-ui-datepicker-and-mvc-view-model-type-datetime/27286969#27286969)) and if its server side, then its because you server does not accept dates in `dd/MM/yyyy` format

Comment: And you have 2 correct answers to your original question! If you then have another question, then ask another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MM is the name of the month (December) you want mm - the month's number (12).

plus - yy is enough to get the year, you wrote it twice (yyyy) so you're getting it twice: `$('#DateTime').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });`

have a look at this as well:
https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/date-formats.html

**EDIT**

dd/mm/yy is not a valid date to systems (bummer, I know) I use php mostly but yy-mm-dd works on all the systems I know, so you should try `$('#DateTime').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });`

if you want it to be displayed in dd/mm/yy but posted in yy-mm-dd you'll need to use the altField and altFormat options of the date picker: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-altField

Answer (score 1):

You need to lower case yout 'MM':

```
$('#DateTime').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });
```

According to datepicker documentation:

> mm - month of year (two digit)
>
> M - month name short
>
> MM - month name long

Take a look at:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906725/unobtrusive-validation-in-chrome-wont-validate-with-dd-mm-yyyy