# How to parse a date in the dd.mm.yyyy format?

Tags: javascript, date, javascript-globalize

I try to parse a date in the `dd.mm.yyyy`format:  `Globalize.parseDate(value, "dd.MM.yyyy", "en");` but globalize crashes with errors:

> Uncaught Error: E_INVALID_PAR_TYPE: Invalid `options` parameter
>   (dd.mm.yyyy). Plain Object expected.
>       at createError (globalize.js:105)
>       at validate (globalize.js:182)
>       at validateParameterType (globalize.js:257)
>       at validateParameterTypePlainObject (globalize.js:295)
>       at Function.Globalize.dateParser.Globalize.dateParser (date.js:1853)
>       at Function.Globalize.parseDate.Globalize.parseDate (date.js:1908)
>       at $.validator.methods.date (Index:1891)
>       at $.validator.check (jquery.validate.js:759)
>       at $.validator.checkForm (jquery.validate.js:450)

Linked script files:

```
<script src="/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/message.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/globalize/date.js"></script>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? What makes you think those are valid `parseDate` parameters?

Comment: Could we see your code? i wish to help but it's quite vague.

Comment: @JJJ, yeah, I read it [here](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize#date-module). But it's very short and I got a nothing from it. So, I found a [sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906725/unobtrusive-validation-in-chrome-wont-validate-with-dd-mm-yyyy).

Comment: That sample is for an old version of the library. The documentation you linked to is not "very short": it says `.parseDate( value [, options] )` is an alias for `.dateParser( [options] )( value )` and that has comprehensive documentation ([here](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/blob/master/doc/api/date/date-parser.md) and [here](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/blob/master/doc/api/date/date-formatter.md)).

Comment: @JJJ, thank you for link, it is more clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the function a value and then an options object.

```
Globalize.locale('en');
Globalize.parseDate(value, {
    skeleton: 'dd.MM.yyyy'
});
```

You can find the documentation for this [here](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/blob/master/doc/api/date/date-parser.md#example).

Comment: Thank you, it works perfect! Although, I got a new bug I think that it doesn't load all cldr js files, so I will try to load these and check again. But the current error disappeared.

Comment: Make sure to read the docs as they have most of this stuff in them. I've never used this before and it took me seconds to find the reason it wasn't working.

Comment: The problem is not in docs, the problem that I very bad know JS but docs orientied on this.